If a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is Cesàro summable & $a_n=O(\frac{1}{n})$, how to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges to the same value?
If the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ is Cesàro summable and $n a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, then the series converges gives the proof of the easier version of the proposition, but I have no clue how to use the $O(\frac{1}{n})$ condition.
I've tried to prove that it's not possible to constrain $a_n$ to $O(\frac{1}{n})$, so that only if $a_n=o(\frac{1}{n})$ then the series is Abelian summable, so I can go back to the link above to solve it. However, I failed in this part.
Also, if it's needed to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k-1}{n}a_n=0$, then I've known that we should use both the $o(\frac{1}{n})$ condition and the Abelian summable condition. That's the furthest part I can go.

I think the improvement of $o(1/n)$ to $O(1/n)$ is due to Littlewood.

@GEdgar For Abel sums, sure. Do you have a reference for the Cèsaro case?
